# How to control various log sizes

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have cluster running in Azure.

I have multiple gigabytes of log data under D:\SvcFab\Log\Traces. Is there way to control amount of trace data that is collected/stored? Will the logs grow indefinitely?

Also the D:\SvcFab\ReplicatorLog has 8GB of preallocated data as specified by SharedLogSizeInMB parameter (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-configuration). How can I change this setting in Azure cluster or should it always be kept default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Azure clusters the SvcFab\Log folder will grow up to 5GB.  It will also shrink if detects your disk is running out of space (<1GB). There are no controls for this in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

This may be old but if you still have this issue, the solution for this is to add parameter in arm template for service fabric cluster .. there are some other ways to do this but this one is the most guaranteed one 
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-developer-blog/reduce-log-size-on-service-fabric-node/ba-p/1017493

Comment: Please consider adding more of your answer in the space provided. You could add some code, and while external links are good, posting the relevant info here is much better.

Comment: what you need to do is to add one parameter to azure service fabric MaxDiskQuotaInMB, you can set this in your ARM template like this 
  {
   "name": "Diagnostics", 
    "parameters": [  
      {
       "name": "MaxDiskQuotaInMB", 
       "value": "65536"
         }
       ] 
    }
or you can make this from console by following these steps 
1- open azure console ==> service fabric clusters ==> choose your cluster 
2- open custom fabric settings ==> add new ==> its section should be Diagnostics but its not here so choose anyone and add it